# Format a generic cell to date

Tags: excel

I've just imported an CSV into Excel. Everything looks nice, but there are no formatted columns.
One of the columns contains values in the format YYYYMMDD (for instance 20120102 for Jan 2nd 2012).
Is there any way that I can format the cell so it automatically transforms this text into a date? I would not like to create a new column.

Comment: Yes, you can format the whole column as dates. Select the whole column, right click, "format cells", number, date. See e.g. http://www.excel-easy.com/basics/format-cells.html

Comment: Yes, but Excel doesn't seem to recognize the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your values and run this small macro:

```
Sub MakeDates()
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        r.Value = DateSerial(Mid(v, 1, 4), Mid(v, 5, 2), Right(v, 2))
    Next r
End Sub
```